# SSIS - how to save file from FTP as Unicode

Tags: sql, file, ftp, ssis

i need to get a txt file from ftp server into a local folder in my own server, and to save it as Text Unicode. how can i do the "saving as" part?

thanks

Comment: FTP Task entry on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137656.aspx

Is there a particular issue you're having with the task? It's pretty straightforward to set an FTP connection manager, create an FTP task, local path, remote path, you're good to go.

Comment: i know the basics, but how can i change the file to Unicode? maybe create a Unicode empty file  as the source?..

Comment: The file on the remote server is also unicode or is your desire to take an ASCII file and save it as Unicode? If Unicode, do you need UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32? Big-endian or little-endian?